# HPlip no funciona. Tengo HP laserjet p1005. no imprime en 23.04

Tags: 23.04

HPlip doesn't work. I have hp laserjet p1005. does not print on 23.04
It won't let me install hplip. and it doesn't print **hp p1005**

"HPlip no funciona. Tengo HP laserjet p1005. no imprime en 23.04
no me permite instalar hplip. y no imprime **hp p1005**"